# How can I develop an InfoPath dropdown field that displays data from a separate SharePont list?

Tags: 2013, list, infopath, infopath-data-connections

I am developing an InfoPath template from a library. I would like for it to connect to a separate list in the same site and display data based on a selection from a drop down on the form.

The drop down field should contain all the unique identifiers from a SharePoint list. Then, when the user selects one, it populates a few of the other fields on the form with the data that is associated with that item.

Comment: UPDATE: So I figured out how to populate the drop down with all the list items in a separate list. Now I just need to know how to populate the other fields in the form with data from the item that is selected.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a subform that uses another data connection for your 2nd list. You can base what populates the subform from what's selected in your drop down.

Here's a video demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=85b7ftTJYo8

Hope this helps.